# computing data source with sessionScope variable - variable gets set to null on partial and full refresh

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

I am attempting to use a sessionScope variable to store a document id to identify the document to assign from the defined datasource.
In beforePageLoad, I create a document collection and do a simple search.  If the document is not found, a new document is created otherwise the existing document is loaded.  All well and good.
The problem: The sessionScope variable is set to null when I do a full or partial refresh of the page.  Despite multiple print statements everywhere, I cannot find where this is occurring.  Many internet searches have not produced information.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xp_1="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.ABBR="ASU";
sessionScope.uniSearchFormula = '@Contains(U_Abbr; "'+ sessionScope.ABBR + '")';
var checkExist:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(sessionScope.uniSearchFormula);
var docid:NotesDocument = checkExist.getFirstDocument();

if (docid == null) {
    print("Creating New Document")
    var docid = database.createDocument();
    docid.replaceItemValue("Form","University");
    docid.replaceItemValue("U_Abbr", sessionScope.ABBR);
    docid.replaceItemValue("U_Name", sessionScope.UniversityName);
    docid.replaceItemValue("U_ContactName","Meerkat Watson");
    docid.save();
} else {
    print("Modifying Existing Document")
    docid.replaceItemValue("U_ContactName","Meerkat Watson");
    docid.save();
}
sessionScope.docid = docid;}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="UniversityDoc" formName="University"
            action="editDocument" loaded="true" documentId="#{javascript:sessionScope.docid}">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:panel id="ButtonPanel">
        <xp:div align="center">
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:button id="button3" value="Refresh Page">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.reloadPage()}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td align="center">
                        <xp:button id="button2" value="Full Update">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                refreshMode="complete">
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:button id="button1" value="Partial Update">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                refreshMode="partial" id="eventHandler2" refreshId="OutputPanel">
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:div>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:panel id="OutputPanel">
        <xp:div align="center">
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="sessionScope.docid = " id="label1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="#{javascript:sessionScope.docid}" id="label11">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label id="label2" value="University Name"></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{UniversityDoc.U_Name}"></xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label id="label3" value="University Abbr"></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{UniversityDoc.U_Abbr}"></xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:div>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

A more experienced colleague here at my office helped me think through this. I was getting the document with the statement:
       var doc:NotesDocument = checkExist.getFirstDocument();
This returns a typeof lotus.domino.local.Document.

I needed to use 
       var docid = doc.getUniversalID()
to get the UNID that the xpage could use to find the document to return which is typeof string.

It seems that one is a pointer and the other is the actual document, but the value is the same for both.  Just the type is different.  Which is something I am still trying to wrap my head around especially since once I set sessionScope.docid = docid, the sessionScope.docid returns a typeof undefined.....

But it is working now.

Comment: Similar to LotusScript where there's a front end and backend document.  The same concept kinda exists in XPages, where there's an XSPDocument which is like the front end UIDocument.

Comment: If you need more foundational information there's around 199 shows on XPages over at the website XPages.TV.  It's a collection of the NotesIn9 videos.  Around 94 hours of info - but many of the early ones are quite short and may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks David - I have watched many of the NotesIn9 video and will make sure I check out some of the early ones.  One of the challenges in my learning curve is the fact that I never developed in Notes when before Xpages and my knowledge of LotusScript is very limited.  I have a fair amount of shell scripting and mysql query knowledge from my past jobs as a systems administrator.  But no real web programming until I started in this job about 1 and 1/2 years ago.

Comment: Lisa - Just an FYI that I think NotesIn9 #160 started a small series for the new developer that did NOT assume previous Notes Dev knowledge.  It was an attempt for people starting from scratch.  Not sure I ever really finished that series but there were 8 episodes that might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, David - I bookmarked the first episode and will take a look at them.

Comment: David,  I am sorry but I have not had a chance to look at those episodes, but I may have figured something out.  Please tell me if I am correct or not.  XSP document looks like: com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument@51275127 and the backend documents are referred to by the DocID or the UNID.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. You're using a runtime calculation (`#{javascript:...}`), so the documentId is recalculating after each partial refresh. Use `${javascript:...}`.

Without `ignoreRequestParams="true"` set on the datasource, it's picking up the settings from the URL. Because there's nothing in the URL, you're getting a new document every time.

That will solve the creation, but you may well hit a problem I covered in my session at IBM Connect at the start of the year. When attached to the top-level XPage, a `dominoDocument` datasource gets calculated *before* `beforePageLoad` runs - it has to because there is no component added to the component tree for it to be bound to. You'll confirm this with print statements in `beforePageLoad` and `documentId` properties, then looking at the server console. Place it within a panel and it runs. To solve this, put it inside a Panel. If it's attached to a Custom Control, because the Custom Control (usually) gets put inside another component, you're fine. Alternatively, set the sessionScope variable outside the form itself.

See Twin Pines Mall / Lone Pine Mall section of my slides here http://www.slideshare.net/paulswithers1/ad1279-marty-youre-not-thinking-fourth-dimensionally-troubleshooting-xpages. I'm afraid you've hit most of the pitfalls I covered in that section.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the ignoreRequestParams property - I will be sure it set to true.

Comment: I did notice via my many print statements that the documentid was being calculated a lot.  Question:  #{javascript} is a runtime calculation - what is ${javascript:}?  I have not heard of runtime # versus $.  I will definitely peruse your presentation for pointers.  At least those pointers that I can understand with my still limited xpages programming knowledge.:>)

Comment: `${javascript:...}` runs only once, on page load. If you don't need to change the value once the page loads, it's better for performance.

Comment: Lisa - you've likely seen Radio buttons where it says "Compute Dynamically" and "Compute on Page Load"  #{} = dynamic and ${} = Compute on PageLoad.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not yet sure about the "null" part but I don't think you're doing it correctly.  If you have a bound dataSource like that, I could be wrong but I thought it it was passed in a blank - then it knows to create a new document and if it's passed in a UNID then it uses that.
Assuming I'm right.. and I might not be, but that would bean you don't need to pre-create a document on beforePageOpen.  Just let it do that for you and then fill in any missing fields on the save.  Or if you need then on the screen just get them live from sessionScope.

I'm not sure what you're doing with that search thing.  Seems like a getDocumentByKey is possibly might be better since you're just looking for a single document.  Though honestly I wonder if you would be better off passing your key in via a parameter and using that.

Just some thoughts.  Not sure if there was a great answer in there.

Comment: I think you have some good ideas to improve the flow of the code.  I will look into the getDocumentbyKey and allowing the xpage to create the document instead of doing it in the beforePageLoad.

Comment: getDocumentbyKey rocks.